# Problem with routing in Angular 2 in production

Tags: angular, routes, production

I made a page in Angular 2 with routing, the project in localhost works fine, but it gets in production (ng build --prod) something goes wrong.

I ulploaded the files on 'dist' folder in the bucket, for going to the page I put https//:*URL*/index.html, the page have a default rounting (/events), so when i enter into the index it redirects to /events, it works fine, and all other rouings too.

The problem is when i refresh the page or if I enter https//:*URL*/events it doesn't find the path and throw me this:
[image]

This is in app-routing.module.ts:

[image]

Comment: when you go to url with no index.html, does it work?

Comment: where are you deploying your angular app, which server and all ?

Comment: no, it doesn't work if I don't put the url/index.html

Comment: im deploying on bucket in aws s3